# Can I base my GameScene as the basis for a 2nd GameScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, levels

I am seeking a correct alternative method to my current issue. I have tried to create a 2nd GameScene as a basis for a 2nd GameScene in which I was hoping to amend a few of the variables, my problem is that in doing this my Gameplay is completely frozen where nodes should be moving.. I can see everything in the GameScene and when tapped the player animation can rotate upon touch movement, the backgrounds are still and player velocity is not executing.

My logic to copying the the GameScene is as follows:

```
    Import SpriteKit

    enum PhysicsCategory: UInt32 {
    case player = 1
    case damagedplayer = 2
    case ground = 4
    case enemy = 8
    }

    class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    // Code A

    }
```

Underneath this I have split the the next class as follows:

```
   class GameScene1: GameScene {

   // Code B (which is a copy of code A)

   }
```

This is odd because I get no errors in the output console but all GameScene moving objects are not moving.. Having removed the GameScene1 code and running the simulation my objects move and GamePlay is as normal.

I now know the button code I have executing in the MenuScene is working correctly as the background UIColor was changed to prove that the scene was different but using the same content.

```
            if nodeTouched.name == "GameScene1Btn" {
            // Button node displayed in MenuScene

            self.view?.presentScene(GameScene1(size: self.size))
            // Switch to GameScene1:

            }
```

Is there a better way I can do this in Xcode? I have not found any similar searches for this and struggling as an Xcode 'newbie' to get my head around this. This will help with the logic and understanding going forward.

Comment: your scene is probably paused, look it up there are many references on here to this (not from Apple of course) but as of iOS 10 SpriteKit objects start out as paused. in the didMove func in your scene set isPaused = false . you may also need to set each of your child objects to isPaused = false as well

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response on this! I’ll give this a go and let you know! :) sorry just to confirm could the extension of this be required for all node classes? Is this what you mean? Anyhow I’ll try this and run the simulator! :) many thanks!

Comment: Hello, Just wanted to get back, I have spent the afternoon looking at different methods for unpausing gamescene, this inclusive of the child objects - this still does not make a difference :/ I'll continue to investigate. I have seen other topics in reference to working the .sks files direct - Currently working on this now - Can't even find something remotely close to what I am trying to achieve, could be the first person ;)

Comment: my comment is only in regards to objects not moving. your question is not clear and asking different things. you need to adjust the focus to 1 item at a time or this will get marked for closure as being unclear

Comment: Apologise I understand this topic may conflict different elements that I don’t fully understand. My main priority was set out to achieve a duplicated level based from my game scene, I believe I have achieved this as I can run in simulation and see both different scenes..

I believe my focal question should be focused on the overall movement where the physics elements seem to be paused, this makes sense with your commentary earlier in this post. I have since tried to create a func statement which all subclasses which are defined in GameScene are declared as ‘let player.isPaused = false’

Comment: I included all SKnodes in this function block but I get the same result, trying to find a similar topic / experience isn’t easy...